# Cannot create 16-bit LDT segments on kernel 3.8.11

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Running Crossover, I get the warning, Your system does not allow creation of 16-bit LDT segments. I am aware that this was a problem around kernel 3.1.x, but I am on 3.8.11. Also, the fix suggested in many places was `echo 1 > /proc/ldt/abi/ldt16` but I have no such file.